# How to join mysql checkbox table A and checkbox results field in another table B?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got tables as per this sqlFiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df04a/1

```
Onepiece table:

|  ID |  Checkbox_IDs   | 
| 1   | 1,2             |
| 2   | 3               |

checkbox
| ID  | Name            |
|  1  | Luffy           |
|  2  | Zorro           |
```

Please help me with a query, I want all the rows from the "onepiece" table and instead of the checkbox_id column showing "1,2" or "2,3,4", it should show what the numbers link to on the checkbox table:

```
Onepiece results table:

|  ID |  Checkbox_IDs   | 
| 1   | Luffy, Zorro    |
| 2   | Sanji           |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.Name) Names
FROM    OnePiece a
        INNER JOIN CheckBoxes b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.ID, a.Checkbox_ID) > 0
GROUP   BY a.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df04a/34)
- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║        NAMES        ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╣
║  7 ║ Luffy,Zorro         ║
║  8 ║ Sanji               ║
║  9 ║ Sanji,Chopper,Zorro ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╝
```